# I do not want my header row quoted, I have rules for what in data rows is quoted. How do I exclude header row fields from being quoted?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

My use case is simple.

Header row with fields in PascalCase should not be quoted.
Data rows where anything that isn't a number is "quoted".

I cannot figure out how to get the header row to not be quoted. Here is my current hack that doesn't work:

```
config.ShouldQuote = args => !decimal.TryParse(args.Field, out _) && args.Row.Row != 0;
```

My assumption is that Row.Row refers only to data rows not the header row.

There are a few header related fields on the args.Row but I don't see how to tweak them.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was simple with a bit of debugging:

```
config.ShouldQuote = args => !decimal.TryParse(args.Field, out _) && args.Row.Row != 0;
```

should have been

```
config.ShouldQuote = args => !decimal.TryParse(args.Field, out _) && args.Row.Row != 1; // <<<<<<<<<<< header is row 1.
```

I know it's not a pretty hack, but it seems to work. Now I just need to sort dates and the jobs a good-un.